# Different Hash Values from Javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variables, hash, character-encoding

I use an HMAC in both javasript and PHP and get two different values of the HMAC when I run both porgams with the parameters to both functions as variables.  However, if I run them as string literals, then everything works out fine.  I think it has something to do with how the string variables encoded in each language but I do not know how to fix it.  The code that I am using is below.

In the below php function, `$pwd1` is retrieved from the command line.

`$k = hash_hmac('sha1', $pwd1, $salt);`

In the below javascript function, `password` is gotten from a `json.parse(msg)` statement.  Then I use the following HMAC method from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/files/2.5.3-crypto-sha1-hmac.js"></script>
```

that looks like `Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA1,password,salt);`.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to log the output of `json.parse(msg)` to a console? (And if you're in a browser, shouldn't this be `JSON.parse(msg)`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.  There is a difference between the way PHP and Javascript store strings.  When PHP is run from the command line, like I was doing, it stores the string and the carriage return (used for entering the variable) making the the string one character longer than in Javascript which does not store the carriage return.  Therefore, if you want to compare a Javascript string and PHP string in anyway or hash them, you have to take a substring from the PHP variable from 0 to -1 (-1 being length-1) to account for the PHP carriage return.

Comment: There shouldn't be a line break unless you're doing something like `echo foo | php myscript.php` ... in that case you can use the `-n` switch with `echo`

Comment: I was running the php script from the command line so when I entered information, the part that read the information also read the carriage return.  When I wrote what the php script had stored, it stored the information I had printed and the carriage return